# GWT - CSS Style

Tags: css, gwt

in GWT , in my work have flex table , in each flex table cell there is a vertical panel , i want to remove vertical panel borders
i tried    getElement().getStyle().clearBorderColor()    but it does not work
and when using in firebug ,discovered that it take flex table style ??

Answer (score 0):

get it's class/ID and write another style to override the default style.

Comment: ok    , i tried this  , when put   border-style :none , it does not work , but when put border-style : soild it work

Comment: try giving border-style :none !important;

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to add the !important to your css style.

```
.verticalPanel {
 border: none !important;
}
```

You also might look into using celltables this has a resources instance that is easy to override.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
yourVerticalPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.HIDDEN);
```